# Как сделать безграничный экран? - Java

Tags: java, android

Как сделать безграничный экран?

Flag fullscreen и layout nolimits
делают его безграничным, но остоется такая черная полоса сверху, как ее тоже изменить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

достаточно просто открыть тему ваше приложения и добавить 1 строчку

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> // это строчку надо добавить
```

p.s. не помню точно, надо ли выставлять родительскую тему из NoActionBar, поэтому поэксперементируйте

Comment: Также осталась черная полоса